# Epson LX 310 not recognized after a strong lightning clap

Tags: usb, printer, hardware-failure

I have an Epson LX 310 dot matrix printer that was working before a strong lightning clap in our area yesterday.

After the strong lightning clap, the computer connected to the Epson LX 310 showed an error: "USB device not recognized" on the USB port of the Epson LX 310.

I have done

- uninstalling the driver and reinstalling the driver,
- resetting the printer,
- connecting the printer to another computer

but nothing happens. The Epson LX 310 printer is not recognized.

What might be wrong with my printer? Is it possible to connect the printer using its parallel port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the printer has built-in diagnostics, try running those to see if it's working at all.  If this were a multifunction printer, I'd suggest trying the copy function.  After a lightning strike, there could be several problems that I can think of.

1) Computer USB port damaged.  Try another computer with the same USB printer.  If that works, try other ports on the PC (remember, the back of towers has USB ports too).

3) USB cable itself damaged.  Unlikely, but if you have another $3 cable, give it a try.

3) Printer USB port damaged.  Try the parallel port, since you mention it has one.  You might need to get a parallel->usb adapter.  My experience is that attempting to print through a parallel->USB adapter is a hassle, even when everything is in good working order.

4) PC damaged in subtle ways that haven't been discovered yet.  Try printing to another printer through USB.

There are other possible issues, like power supply problems, or subtle software problems  incurred during the storm.  I'm not certain how to test for or resolve them, other than replacing the printer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply. I will consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting the printer to another computer would indicate that the printer USB port has failed, as you suggest.  A quick Google search confirms that your printer has a legacy parallel port.

There are USB to parallel adapters on the market that will likely work to get your connection going again. I've used one on a legacy HP laser with minimal problems. There is the possiblity that you'll lose bi-directional communication, although contemporary USB to parallel adapters are more likely to support that aspect of communications.

I would suggest that you test your computer's USB port to ensure that it is still working. You may have to mark that one as dead and use another.

Comment: Thank you so much for prompt reply. I've already connected the printer to another pc and I've got the same error USB DEVICE NOT RECOGNIZED.

Comment: Unfortunately, the printer is probably damaged and needs to be replaced.  It might be repairable, but it may not be worth your time to try it, compared to getting a replacement.  If a printer is bought recently, the manufacturer might be willing to replace it under warranty, but warranties are generally against flaws in the design or construction, rather than storm damage.  You will probably have to buy another.